# Why is this timestamp invalid?

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I want to extract the Date part from this timestamp `2022-05-25T061538.576403Z`. However, I keep getting invalid timestamp error with both the EXTRACT() and the DATE() functions.
Will appreciate if some insights is available on why is it invalid along with the extract part.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What errors do you hit?

Comment: @Ron I used the DATE( this_timestamp_value ) function as I normally do, I get invalid timestamp error.

Comment: If time part of the string is `06:15:38` , it's a valid timestamp and you can use `DATE()` function to get a Date value.   ex. `2022-05-25T06:15:38.576403Z`

Comment: Or, you can try this : `DATE(LEFT('2022-05-25T061538.576403Z', 10));`

Comment: Hi @xvzf, Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Hi @xvzf, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jaytiger, The issue can be resolved by using below query to extract the Date part from the Timestamp value `2022-05-25T061538.576403Z`.

```
DATE(LEFT('2022-05-25T061538.576403Z', 10));
```